# How to track files in Git-LFS with special characters in file ending?

Tags: git, git-lfs

In my company we use a personal encryption tool, that allows to encrypt single files. It tries to handle en- and decryption transparently for a windows user by storing the encrypted file next to the unencrypted one with a special file ending. This is done automatically and I cannot change this behavior; I cannot rename the file. It adds a symbol to the end of the filename, it looks like the Unicode Dot-Operator '⋅', but I am not sure.

Unencrypted: MyWord.docx
Encrypted: MyWord.docx

in Windows it looks like the Dot-Operator "MyWord.docx⋅"

The git bash and other tools show the file as: MyWord.docx\356\263\260

If I do

```
git-lfs track "*.docx\356\263\260"
```

The file is not tracked by LFS. How can I add this ending with special character correctly to Git-LFS-tracking?

Before you ask: I know, it might be not the best idea to store binary and especially encrypted files in git.

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your repository, the `.gitattributes` file is where the settings are stored for `git lfs track`, you can add the special character to the filename and save. then you can test this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a shell question:

```
$ echo "\356\263\260"
\356\263\260
```

These `"\356\263\260"` are not special characters and are just 12 characters, three times `\` character followed by 3 digits. If you *want* to pass speical characters to a script, you have to use special quoting. Research bash C-quoting in shell and commands `echo` and `printf` for more information.

If that character is [this character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ecf0/index.htm) and your shell is UTF-8, you could just insert it:

```
git-lfs track "*.docx"
```

That character even doesn't render on my font properly, so I copied it from your post. If you which to encode it from utf-8, use the shell methods mentioned above:

```
git-lfs track "*.docx"$'\xEE\xB3\xB0'
git-lfs track "*.docx$(printf "\xEE\xB3\xB0")"
```